# Question about comparing Java's HashMap `find` method and `tieBreakOrder`

Tags: java, hashmap

I've been studying Java's HashMap and a few questions have come up.
Looking at the `find` method of `HashMap`, it is written as follows:

```
else if ((q = pr.find(h, k, kc)) != null)
    return q;
else
    p = pl;
```

In contrast, other methods in `HashMap` such as `putTreeVal` or `treeify` use the `tieBreakOrder` method. I'm curious about the difference between these two.

```
static int tieBreakOrder(Object a, Object b) {
    int d;
    if (a == null || b == null ||
        (d = a.getClass().getName().
         compareTo(b.getClass().getName())) == 0)
        d = (System.identityHashCode(a) <= System.identityHashCode(b) ?
             -1 : 1);
    return d;
}
```

As I see it, both have commonality in traversing tree nodes - the `find` method directly traverses the nodes of the tree while `tieBreakOrder` seems to be comparing several values.

So, I thought about it from the perspective of atomic operations. I assumed that visiting a single node and comparing primitive data values take about the same operation time. As a result, I concluded that the `find` method – which actually traverses nodes – might be faster than `tieBreakOrder`, which compares many primitive values.

However, I'm not sure if my assumption is correct, or if there is any other reason that I can understand more about the difference between the `find` and `tieBreakOrder` methods?

Comment: "`tieBreakOrder`, which compares many primitive values." - I don't see that in the code you posted. It basically checks if any of the arguments is null or if both are of the same class and if so it uses the system identity hash which is based on memory location to determine order - that's it. This is done to maintain order when building trees but `find` doesn't need that because order doesn't change when just reading values.

Comment: @Thomas The system identity hashcode is normally unrelated to the memory location, but gets a value from a random generator when the object is created (though there is a commandline setting to select a different strategy, you can even configure it so that all system identity hashcodes are `1`!)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ah, I see - probably confused that with other mechanisms. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment: if you read the comments in the code, you'll see this for `tieBrakOrder()`:

> Tie-breaking utility for ordering insertions when equal hashCodes and non-comparable. We don't require a total order, just a consistent insertion rule to maintain equivalence across rebalancings. Tie-breaking further than necessary simplifies testing a bit.

This means tie-breaking is necessary to maintain consistent ordering when building the trees which happens during `putTreeVal()` or `treeify()`.

On the other hand, `find()` just uses the order already present in the tree and if you look at the method you'll see a couple of other things being tried first:

- go left or right if the node's hash code is lesser or greater than the one we're looking for
- if the hash code is equal and the key matches as well, we've found the correct node
- if the hash code is equal but the key doesn't match we're in a similar situation as `treeify()` etc.: we need another approach to find the correct node

  - first the method checks if we're at one of the outermost nodes and sends search more inward
  - if we're not at one of the outermost nodes the search direction is determined by comparing the keys, if they are comparable
  - if the keys aren't comparable search is directed to the right first and if nothing is found there it continues to the left (this is the snippet you shared)

As you can see, there's no need for tie-breaking in this logic. Search is done in a deterministic way and will return the same result even if the trees are rebuilt - that's what tie-breaking ensures.

**Edit**: Wouldn't it make sense to use `tieBreakOrder()` in `find()` to determine whether to look left or right? (from a comment)

No, that wouldn't work because tie-breaking uses each key's identity hash code to determine order and that code can seem "random" (i.e. 2 equal instances of the same class can have totally different identity hash codes).

Let's make an example: for the sake of simplicity let's assume the following key class:

```
class Version {
  String value;

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // compare values
  }

  public int hashCode() {  
    // For the sake of simplicity we either return 0 or 1.
    // In reality you'd use a proper algorithm that is unlikely to
    // produce the same hash code for different values albeit it 
    // still could happen
    return value.hashCode() % 2;
  }
}
```

As you can see, if we now have a hash map that uses `Version` as a key it might need to resort to tie-breaking because the instances are likely to have the same hash code, are not guaranteed to be equal and are not comparable.

Let's assume we use the following keys that all happen to have the same hash code (assumption used for the argument):

- `new Version("1.0")`, identity hash code: 1234
- `new Version("2.0")`, identity hash code: 999
- `new Version("3.0")`, identity hash code: 1024

Tie-breaking would now order them as `"2.0", "3.0", "1.0"`.

Now assume you're looking for the entry with key `Version("1.0")`. If you hit the node that contains `"3.0"`, would you search left or right?

If you think "right, because the key's identity hash code is 1234", then think about this: you might not know the exact instances of the key so you generate a new one - `map.get(new Version("1.0"))` - and you'd expect this to work.

However, that new instance gets identity hash code 1001 - would you now search left or right if you hit the `"3.0"` entry?

Comment: Thank you once again for the polite and detailed response.

Comment: I understood that the final logic traverses all nodes from right to left. Hence, I wondered if this was not causing high time complexity, and it reminded me of the tieOrderBreaker method in treeify's logic. I understood this tieOrderBreaker to be a method that returns a dir value determining whether it's the left or right child when a hash collision occurs even with different values. Then, I thought that when there is no comparable, instead of traversing all nodes, you could use the tieBreakOrder method to infer whether it exists on the left or right.

Comment: That is, since treeify and putTreeVal call tieOrderBreaker to determine the child position when they're invoked, I thought it could be used instead of traversal in find.
However, as the tieBreakOrder compares the original hash values and putTreeVal and treeify call the balanceInsertion, and since this method can move the inserted position to a completely different location when operated, it seems that it's an irreplaceable approach.

Could there be an error in my thinking?

Comment: @yong_ta_Park no, you can't use `tieBreakOrder()` in `find()`. The reason is that it just defines a deterministic order between 2 instances of non-comparable keys. If you now search using yet another key instance based on the identity hash code the key could be in between the tie-broken keys, lesser than all of them or greater - you don't know. That's why we basically need a "sequence scan" in that situation. ...

Comment: @yong_ta_Park ... I'll add the comment and an example to my answer as I need more space and formatting options :)

Comment: It seems I overlooked the fact that when searching for values, I often don't use the exact same instance as the key. Additionally, even if hashCode and equals are overridden, the original hash value still exists.

Comment: Because the tieBreakOrder method compares using the original hash value, overriding equals and hashCode in the Version object becomes meaningless. Therefore, I understand that using the tieBreakOrder method in the find method is not feasible, as there's no guarantee that the original hash value of the key I'm looking for and the original hash value I have will be the same.

Did I understand your explanation correctly?

Comment: @yong_ta_Park no, the hash codes will need to be the same even if using different instances of the key. The high level order of a get operation is like this: 1) use the key's hash code to determine the bucket in which the value should be 2) do a linear search of the bucket's list or a binary search of the bucket's tree (it starts with a simple list and if that grows too much it is converted to a tree by using `treeify()`). 3) While walking tree, the hash code is used again to determine direction and finally `equals()` is used to check whether a key with the same hash code is the one we want.

Comment: Thank you for your patient answers despite my ignorance. Here's how I understand it

Comment: 1) The hash code of the key is used to generate a hash value for use in the hashmap, which then determines the bucket value. 2) Initially, the bucket stores data in the form of a singly linked list Node, but when the array size reaches 64 and a single bucket contains more than 8 elements, it is converted into a TreeNode, which combines the form of a red-black tree and Node. 3) In the case of TreeNode, the hash code is used to determine the direction, and finally, equals() is used to find the identical key among those with the same hash code.

Comment: And yes, having the same hash code - overriding hashCode and equals - means that when calling the get() function, you must have the same hash code to find the desired value. When I experimented, most of the time, calling get with a new instance without a unified hash code resulted in null.

Comment: Additionally, thinking further, if tieBreakOrder is used to apply the last condition in find, it seems impossible to ever find the desired value, since the original hash code of each instance is different.

Comment: If I have any misunderstandings or there are things I don't know, I would be grateful if you could further enlighten me.

Thank you for not giving up and for providing detailed and kind answers despite my frustrating questions.

Comment: @yong_ta_Park I'm not sure I can follow all of your comments but the first part is basically right - only "The hash code of the key is used to generate a hash value for use in the hashmap" is not quite right. The hash code _is_ the value used in the map, i.e. to find the bucket it will basically do `key.hashCode() % buckets.length`. This means different hash codes are mapped to the same bucket which is fine. Non-equal keys having the same hash code should be a rare instance if `hashCode()` is implemented properly and according to the "contract" with `equals()` ...

Comment: ... so `tieBreakOrder()` really is used as a last resort if anything else fails. It would still not make much sense to use it in `find()` but even so there should be very few keys to which it applies and thus looking right to left is fine (and necessary as I tried to explain above).